# package-lock.json is not generating

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json, package-lock.json

I am trying to recreate package-lock.json file after installing some new modules from package.json. But somehow it is now stopped generating the updated package-lock.json file.

The npm version I am using is > 5 currently the version is 8.5.2 and node version is 17.4.0

How can I regenerate it while doing npm install

Comment: If you run `npm config get package-lock`, does it say true or false?

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren it say true

Comment: Do you have a npm-shrinkwrap.json-file in your project?

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren yes I have npm-shrinkwrap.json-file in my project

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren and I also do not want to use npm-shrinkwrap.json-file. Does it somehow conflicting in some way?

Comment: Then that will be updated instead of package-lock.json as default if I remember correctly. You could try running `npm install --package-lock-only` and see if that overrides it and generates a `package-lock.json` if you really need one.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren I tried with `npm install --package-lock-only` but `package-lock.json` is not updated

Comment: Yeah then it still prioritizes the shrinkwrap-file. If you don't want that then just remove it and it should generate a package-lock.json on next install but there shouldn't be any reason to have both. So you'll just have to pick one.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren I will try this out and will update you.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren Thank you it worked for me by removing `shrinkwrap-file` :)